# Mailchimp API: Add emails to my app's users' email lists

Tags: api, mailchimp

Is it possible to use Mailchimp API to subscribe emails to the lists of MY USERS' Mailchimp Accounts and not my own?

Basically I have a web app, and users collect emails of various subscribers through this app. I then want them to be able to click a button and subscribe all those emails to their lists.

I've looked at Mailchimp's API - particularly the `/lists/subscribe` and the `/lists/batch-subscribe` methods. However so far it appears that these will only work for your own Mailchimp account and not for remote users' accounts.

Can someone please tell me whether what I'm trying to achieve is possible with Mailchimp's API?

Comment: Isn't this as simple as having your users' api-keys, executing the api-calls with their credentials, this doing stuff to their accounts?

Comment: I suspect it is indeed as simple as that, but how do you get users' api keys? As far as I know the only way is to gain physical (login/password) access to their account right?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to execute the api-calls with your users' api-key, which would mean that you execute the calls with their credentials.

There are three different ways to get their api keys, with different practicality levels.

1. You guess. They look like guids without dashes, and some information about which datacenter it is associated with. Some easy (and somewhat bad) calculations indicate that there are 2^128 api keys in every datacenter, so this will consume both cpu- and network-resources, and invoke the rage of the [Mailchimp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Iul.jpg). The linked image shows him on a good day. He won't be as pleasant if you choose this alternative. Dont do this.
2. You ask, in an evil way, for their username/password. This is bad since it will give you to all accounts those credentials works with. This would also give you access to stuff that aren't available using api calls (like payment stuff). This wont work at all if your user is intelligent administrators that are using [AlterEgo](https://alteregoapp.com/), the two-factory security alternative. This alternative is less bad than blindly guessing, but still provides too much access, if it works at all.
3. You ask, in a user-friendly way (with perhaps some quick tutorials), for the user to generate an api-key in mailchimp to provide to you. This is the Good Alternative (tm).

You may choose any implementation as long as you choose number three.